# Hyperledger Composer query processor function returning a blank array

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to write a query processor function in Hyperledger Composer. However, it is just returning an empty array '[]' and I am not sure why. When doing a GET request from 'org.land.Deal'. I have 2 items being returned. But from the query processor function, only the blank array is being returned.

Here is the transaction function:

```
/**
* Get Live Deals
* @param {org.land.GetLiveDeals} getLiveDeals - the transaction
* @transaction
*/

async function getLiveDeals(){
  const liveDeals = [];
  const dealRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.land.Deal');
  const allDeals = await assetRegistry.getAll();

  for(const deal of allDeals){
    liveDeals.push(deal);
  }

  return liveDeals;
}
```

Here is the transaction model:

```
@commit(false)
@returns(Deal[])
  transaction GetLiveDeals {
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `const allDeals = await dealRegistry.getAll();`?

Comment: @JonDockter Yes! Don't know how I didn't catch that

Answer (score 0):

I hope this change will work out;

> const allDeals = await dealRegistry.getAll();

For more info please do refer - [Composer getAll()](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/runtime-assetregistry#getall)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Unfortunately, the change doesn't make a difference. It's still returning an empty array.

Comment: @Ronald Long, Do you have data in asset `Deal`? and which version of the composer are you using?